# How to create a Social Proof plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to create a social proof plugin for my wordpress application so that when users are logging in, other online users will see a pop up notification showing the user that logged in and their geolocation via googlemaps. The closest thing I could find to what I was looking for was on https://wpfomify.com.

Does anyone have any idea the steps I would take to creating a plugin like this particularly how the site will communicate to online users that a new notification has been queued. Thanks.

Comment: You would need a javascript AJAX call to poll the server for new messages. You can use `wp-ajax` to create endpoints for your javascript functions. The endpoint should return messages / meta in JSON format.

Comment: The messages could be posts of a custom post type you create. The meta like sender, receiver, read status and date/time could be stored in meta fields.

Comment: For more info on wp-ajax see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)